# How do I import several tkinter apps into an app which offers the choice of the 4?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two tkinter programs that work as desired. I would like to create a third Tkinter program to offer a user the choice of the two (I hope to have 4 eventually). I would use the import statement to include them. I am not sure of the proper structure to design to avoid multiple tk instance and multiple main loops. Any input on options or reference to examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Just make your 3rd program as the root and change others to `Toplevel`.